# Is there a way in C++ to pass arguments by name like in python?

Tags: c++, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Is there a way in C++ to pass arguments by name like in python?
For example I have a function:

```
void foo(int a, int b = 1, int c = 3, int d = 5);
```

Can I somehow call it like:

```
foo(5 /* a */, c = 5, d = 8);
```

Or

```
foo(5, /* a */, d = 1);
```

Comment: [Aggregate inits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) can have designators, but it's a C++20 feature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are no named function parameters in C++, but you can achieve a similar effect with designated initializers from C++20.

Take all the function parameters and put them into a struct:

```
struct S 
{
    int a{}, b{}, c{}, d{};
};
```

Now modify your function to take an instance of that struct (by `const&` for efficiency)

```
void foo(S s) 
{
    std::cout << s.a << " " << s.b << " " << s.c << " " << s.d;  // for example
}
```

and now you can call the function like this:

```
foo({.a = 2, .c = 3});  // prints 2 0 3 0 
                        // b and d get default values of 0
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/neTdeP)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and It seems like a neat approach. But can it be referred to as a good practice or would it be referred to as a gimmick?

Comment: @Ahmn21 It's a relatively modern feature, as it's only been in the language for a few years, so it's a bit early to say if this is good practice. However, it's perfectly valid code, and I would say it's quite a reasonable way to achieve something like named parameters. There aren't any downsides to this approach as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @cigien The downside of having to define an extra struct, that you don't then know if it's used for more than one function, the burden of having several similar structs because there are several functions that receives tiny variations of the same set of parameters...  I would love C++ to have some sort of possibility of, if not "designated arguments", at least the possibility of definining "inline structs" or something like that. Types that are defined "tied" to the signature of a function, that only exists because that particular function exists.

Answer (score 5):

**No**
You have to pass the arguments by order, so, to specify a value for `d`, you must also specify one for `c` since it's declared before it, for example.